# Onclick doesn't work normally and move button to the next line doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom

I use jsfiddle run it and the source code is  http://jsfiddle.net/eVyjC/12/

I want to add a button to start and stop number changing. I use a div containing
 six spans, each has a number.

Then I use createElement to create a input button and set onclick to run the user-defined 
function setInterval(keepMove) but it doesn't work and no any error come out?

And then I test by use alert, to my surprise it run when load the page without click the 
button?

My questions are:

1.Why the onclick run first when loading and how to let it run by clicking the button as I expect?

2.I try to add a br to the last span to move the button to the next line, but it doesn't work. What's do I wrong and how can I fix it?

Thx you for reading my problem, I have tried to figure it serveral days and try many methods but don't work.(eg document.write html tag or createElement and Childappend )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Instead of:

```
buttonNode.onclick= alert('WhyIFirstRunQQ');
```

Do:

```
buttonNode.onclick= function(){ alert('WhyIFirstRunQQ'); }
```

That should do the trick.

2: Use `document.write("<br>");`

I strongly recommend using a javascript library such as jQuery instead of doing all this by hand.

Comment: Thx, after I add the function, it work only when I press the button. But I still doesn't know the reason. What is the difference between them?